Issue with loading JRuby Gems on Tomcat 9
I am using JRuby within a Spring 5 non-Boot application. I use javax.script with JRuby as an implementation to script some parts of my application.
Ruby scripts are located outside the compiled WAR file and are loaded into a ScriptEngine via a path defined in application.properties on my local filesystem. Some scripts may use Ruby Gems which are provided in a jar declared as a Maven dependency. I created this jar using the technique described in this article: http://blog.nicksieger.com/articles/2009/01/10/jruby-1-1-6-gems-in-a-jar/
Gems can be loaded in a Ruby script by simply doing this:
require 'rest-client'

In the development environment, we use Jetty 9.4 with the Jetty Maven plugin, but in the production environment, we use Tomcat.
Everything works as intended with Jetty 9.4 and Tomcat 7, and I can require my Gems successfully. However, on Tomcat 9, I can no longer require my gems. The following error is displayed:
LoadError: no such file to load -- rest-client

As a workaround, I found out that if I put my gems.jar directly into the ${CATALINA_HOME}/lib folder, it resolves the issue.
I am aware that there have been changes to resource loading since Tomcat 8. Therefore, when I migrated to Tomcat 9, I had to change some paths in my Spring WS Dynamic WSDL config to use absolute paths instead of relative ones.
How can I get this to work as it did previously ?
